# What is the use of @vocab in JSON-LD and what is the difference to @context?

Tags: rdf, json-ld

What is the `@vocab` attribute in JSON-LD for? As I see it you can "import" a remote vocabulary, but isn't this the same you can do with `@context`? If I'm not wrong then you can "import" a remote source for `@context` as well. So where is the difference between `@vocab` and `@context`?

Extra question: Can I have more then one `@vocab`? For example the first referrers to schema.org and the other to rdfs?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

`@vocab` is used specifically to declare a *default* vocabulary from which all terms derive, without having to declare specific mappings for each term (as you normally do in a `@context`).

For example, see this snippet (taken from the [JSON-LD 1.0 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/json-ld/)):

```json
{
  "@context": {
    "@vocab": "http://schema.org/"
  }
  "@id": "http://example.org/places#BrewEats",
  "@type": "Restaurant",
  "name": "Brew Eats"
  ...
}
```

In this fragment, `@vocab` is used to define that in this context, all terms derive from the schema.org vocabulary. So in the following fragments, `Restaurant` maps to `http://schema.org/Restaurant`, and `name` maps to `http://schema.org/name`. You could of course have done this with explicit mappings in the `@context` as well:

```json
{
  "@context": {
    "Restaurant": "http://schema.org/Restaurant",
    "name" : "http://schema.org/name" 
  }
  "@id": "http://example.org/places#BrewEats",
  "@type": "Restaurant",
  "name": "Brew Eats"
  ...
}
```

but this quickly becomes tedious as you start using more and more terms from the same vocabulary. `@vocab` is just a useful short way to say: "if I don't have an explicit mapping for a term, this is what it maps to".

As for whether you can use more than one `@vocab`: you can have more than one `@vocab` in a JSON-LD document (just as you can have more than one `@context`), but you can not have more than one in the same `@context`. I trust that the explanation that it defines a default also makes it clear why you can't have two in the same context.

Comment: In other words: this is the way you define the empty-prefix? Hope you get what mean.